# Linking failure [ld cannot find library]

Tags: linux, gcc, libraries, linker

I am trying to configure Linux kernel [Angstrom distribution] via `make menuconfig`, but I get these errors.

```
make: Warning: File `/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.61/arch/arm/Makefile' has modification time 11511 s in the future
make[1]: Warning: File `scripts/Makefile.host' has modification time 11393 s in the future
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
```

The same occurs when I tried to compile Hello_world.c program.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I noticed that libgcc_s.so is missing. How can i fix this? Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What compiler is this? And can you reproduce the problem with a hello world example? We had someone with a similar error just a little while ago...

Comment: Angstrom users are advised not to manually install gcc, libgcc etc but task-native-sdk (`opkg install task-native-sdk`). I 'll try with Hello_world.c and I let you know.

Comment: Same thing with Hello_world.c program.

Comment: Post the output of `gcc --version`.

Comment: `gcc version 4.3.3 (GCC)`

Comment: Check that your gcc is properly installed. Did you did install your distribution's binary gcc package?

Answer (score 4):

It will depend on where the file is, in my case it works like this:

```
:~$ locate gcc_s
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so
```

And you have to make sure that path is present in one of the ld.so.conf files like:

```
:~$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

But this is Debian x86_64

```
:~$ gcc -lgcc_s sample.c -o sample
:~$ ldd sample
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6a9ff000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8e95a29000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8e9569f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8e95c4a000)
```

Comment: The only libgcc_s.so1 is located on `/lib` directory. `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3` directory doesn't contain anything similar. I guess I 'll have to download libgcc_s.so.

Comment: If you're cross compiling you'll have to complile the libraries as well, is /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 for x86(_64)?